# lightning:listview component: unable to display list views from managed packages

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have an app page that needs to display records from a particular list view. I have created a simple component using lightning:listview component.

I am able to use this to display a custom list view for a managed package object. But when I try to display a managed package list view for the same managed package object I get a message "The list view you requested was deleted, or you don't have permission to view it".

I am logged in as the system administrator. I can view the contents of the list view if I go that object's tab and select that list view.
The code for my sample component is below.

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<lightning:listView aura:id="listViewAccounts"
                    objectApiName="namespace__objectname__c"
                    listName="All"
                    rows="5"
                    showActionBar="true"
                    enableInlineEdit="true"
                    showRowLevelActions="true"
                    /></aura:component>
```

The error message that I am seeing [image]

Let me know if you can spot what I am doing wrong. Your response will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am using the developer name for "listname" attribute of the component. I have verified it by running the query "select name, developername, sobjecttype from listview". I have also verified that the listview is part of the managed package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [lightning:listView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_listView.htm)documentation says that `listName`  is "The developer name of the List View" so something to try to access a list view that is in the managed package would be to add the managed package's namespace prefix. Assuming that is "xyz":

```
listName="xyz__All"
```

Also are you sure the list view "All" is in the managed package?

Comment: Hi @keith, Yes, I am using the developer name of the list view. I verified it by running the query "select name, developername, sobjecttype from listview". The listview is part of the managed package.

Comment: any object or component that is part of a managed package should have the namespace prefix before it's developer name. so @ReddyRachamallu please check really good with which components you are playing

Comment: Hi @Itai, Thanks. Adding the namespace prefix to the list view name did the trick. I should have tried it before posting.